# Conditional formatting error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to write some vba code that adds conditional formatting to a sheet, however I keep running into an application defined error. The following is my code

```
With sheet1.Range("C2:C")
  .FormatConditions.Delete
  .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK($B2))"
  .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(225, 242, 255)
End With
```

Any suggestions on why this could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: What line does the error appear on? Correct me if i'm wrong but `Range("C2:C")` is not a valid range?

Comment: You look like you're specifying the start cell row but not including the last cell row.. are you looking for a way to dynamically add that number?

Comment: Thanks you're right, I just changed the range to include an end row. But now I'm getting a "subscript out of range error" for the Interior.ColorIndex line of the code?

Comment: Replace `.ColorIndex =` with just `.Color =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range("C2:C")` is not a valid range, make it fixed, or the following makes it dynamic:

Then change your `ColorIndex` to just `Color`:

```
With Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
  .FormatConditions.Delete
  .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISBLANK($B2))"
  .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(225, 242, 255)
End With
```